# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown> in ListFragment with sliding tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listfragment, layout-inflater

My Logcat is as follows:

```
09-30 01:02:26.708    2545-2545/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-30 01:02:26.709    2545-2545/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.swati.newsaggregator, PID: 2545
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.example.swati.newsaggregator.FeedListAdapter.getView(FeedListAdapter.java:65)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:
09-30 01:02:26.710    1233-1247/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.example.swati.newsaggregator/.MainActivity
```

This is the xml file that cannot be inflated:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/feed_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:textColorLink="@color/link" />

    <com.example.swati.newsaggregator.FeedImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code for ListFragment

```
    public class BnewsFragment extends ListFragment {


private static final String ARG_CATEGORY = "category";
private String mcategory;
private final String TAG = "LIST_FRAG";
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private View mView;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "some URL";

public static BnewsFragment newInstance(String category) {
    BnewsFragment fragment = new BnewsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_CATEGORY, category);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public BnewsFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mcategory = getArguments().getString(ARG_CATEGORY);
    }

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getContext(), feedItems);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView inflated!");
    mView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, true);
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        Log.d(TAG,"Cache not empty!");
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        Log.d(TAG, "making fresh volley request cache empty");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "InitialResponse: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Successful non-null response!");
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG,"request error!" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
    return mView;
}

       /* @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}*/

/*@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}*/

/*@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }
}*/

private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");
        Log.d(TAG,"inside parseJsonfeed");
        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            Log.d(TAG, feedObj.getString("title"));
            //item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            //item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            //String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
            //        .getString("image");
            //item.setImge(image);
            item.setImge(null);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("title"));
            //item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            //item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            //String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
            //        .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(null);
            feedItems.add(item);
        }
        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In a simple listView, this file was successfully inflated. But as soon as i added it to a custom ListFragment, this error is popping up. Right now, i have not parsed any image.

Comment: Post your ListFragment code.

Comment: Hey, I have added the ListFragment code as well.

Comment: Try to call *setListAdapter(listAdapter);* in onCreateView() instead of onCreate().

Comment: I tried that too. Alternatively, when I try to add a custom listView inside a fragment instead of a ListFragment, and set its adapter inside onCreateView(), it still gives me the exact same error!

Comment: Add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your main `LinearLayout`

Comment: I'm getting an error specifically at this line inside custom FeedListAdapter's getView() :-
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item,parent);

Comment: Give a try with *inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);*

Comment: Tried that too. Although now the error says BINARY XML file line #3 instead of #2

Answer (score 0):

Since you have overridden the onCreateView in the ListFragment you layout file(list_fragment.xml) should contain a listView.

Refer to the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Sorry, posting this as an answer because I don't have the 50 rep points to make a comment.

Comment: It does contain a listView and an alternative textView for an empty list. The problem is with the feed_item.xml which defines the layout for each row of the list.

Comment: You are missing </LinearLayout> in the end of the xml layout. But that should be a compile error. Also I think you should try removing all the and just have one TextView in the layout and then test and see if it works. Posting the code for the Adaptor might help.